# MapBox, Google Maps and big datasets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, geolocation, maps, mapbox

Could you please explain me how to work with big datasets in Mapbox and GMaps? Let me explain - imagine you have service with big amount of points (for example - directory of lost things around the world) and you need to show to users points in his region. Currently I see only those options:

- allow to download entire database to the client (browser or mobile), but it will take a lot of traffic :(
- determine on client visible bounds of map and send information about visible area to application server on each zoom in/out, but it may take a lot of requests to application server.

In both cases I will need to deal with clustering API to keep map useful for users.

But, as I understand - there are Dataset API on mapbox and Data layer on google maps to deal with big amount of data without application server (only with S3 in mapbox). Could you explain me best practices and show examples how to work with big amount of points?